# Perfomance issues saving EditText text to Database

Tags: android

I have an EditText in my Android Application where I am using addTextChangedListener to save the text to database. 
But the events are triggering everytime user inputs a key.  I feel this is unnecessary.

Can you show me a better way to save the text after user finished typing.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //Sure Not here... 
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Saving text from here ??
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //Saving text from here ??
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to save on any button click ? or while typing ? why don't you remove addTextChangedListener and use **editText.getText()**

Comment: You can check for the next keycode press for saving, or a better option would be to use a submit button at the end for saving the data from all the edittexts altogether.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma I don't want to save on button click. The text to be saved as a user types it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve performance you can use delay in firing your queries after each type, try the following:

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            private var timer = Timer()
            private val DELAY: Long = 300 // milliseconds, 300 are enough

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                timer.cancel()
                timer = Timer()
                timer.schedule(
                        object : TimerTask() {
                            override fun run() {
                                // perform your task here
                                if (s!!.length > 2 || s.isEmpty()) {
                                    // or you can use this character limit check optionally 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        DELAY
                )
            }

        })
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Could be best option to save input text on focus lost, this will ensure that user has done with editing and moved out from that input field.

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if (!hasFocus) {
        // save your data , editText.getText()
      }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Will this event trigger all times ?

Comment: No, only on focus change. Look at here [OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener)